# Playa - multiple selections - limit to 4

Tags: playa, zoo-visitor

EE 2.5.5
PLaya 4.4.1
Zoo Visitor 1.3.23

On this site I have members who can edit their profile and select divisions that they belong to (playa). On the front end I can easily limit the display of their profile to only 4 divisions - :)

However on the divisions section of the site - Each division lists all members of that division using exp:playa:parents. The issue is how do I limit it so that a member only appears in the first 4 divisions that they have selected? As it stands I have a test member who is in 10 divisions and **they appear in all divisions**, however on their member profile only the first 4 divisions are displayed.

Ideally when setting up the playa field and selecting Allow multiple selections I could limit the number of selections but that doesn't appear to be possible.

Comment: update - On Twitter Brandon Kelley has said he will add this to the next version of Playa.

Answer (score 1):

Could you simply have 4 playa fields limited to a single selection each?

Answer (score 1):

looks like this options is still not in Playa.

*Solution:*

*/themes/third_party/playa/scripts/droppanes.js*

replace

```
var selectItems = function($items) {
```

with

```
var selectItems = function($items) {

    obj.limit = $items.parents("label:first").data('limit');
    obj.totalSelect = obj.selectionsSelect.$items.length + 1;

    if (obj.totalSelect > obj.limit) {
        obj.optionsSelect.deselectAll(true);
        return false;
    }
```

SafeCracker/Zoo Visitor template code (*data-limit* is how many options can user choose)

```
       <label class="input" data-limit="3">
                {field:playa_field}         
       </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this without building a custom add-on will probably be quite tricky. The only way I can think of is by using a Matrix field limited to 4 rows, with a single-select Playa field in one of the columns. Not a particularly great experience for editing your profile, but it would work.

Edit to add: the upside would be that you could store extra data against each selection very easily, should the site's requirements ever grow.